# How to splice dictionary javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
{
    1: {
        "title": title,
        "name": name,
        "etc": etc
    },
    2: {
        "title": title,
        "name": name,
        "etc": etc
    },
    3: {
        "title": title,
        "name": name,
        "etc": etc
    },
    4: {
        "title": title,
        "name": name,
        "etc": etc
    },
    5: {
        "title": title,
        "name": name,
        "etc": etc
    },
    6: {
        "title": title,
        "name": name,
        "etc": etc
    }
}
```

I tryed something like this but with no change of working..

My question is .. how can i divide this dictionary in more dictionaries (pages).
I want to use it later for a angularjs pagination.
Any idea or suggestion will be apreciated.Thank you!

Comment: i dont understand the comment..

Comment: Well, you iterate over objects using `for`

Comment: do you know the numbers of items in your object?

Comment: no .. i get an dictionary with items for every category of products i search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using arrays for this instead, because objects in javascript aren't intended to adhere to a fixed order like this so it's strange that you're using a dictionary like an array - anyway:

```
function spliceDict(dict, minKey, maxKey) {
  var newDict = {};
  for(var i in dict) {
    if(i >= minKey && i <= maxKey) {
      newDict[i] = dict[i];
    }
  }
  return newDict;
}
```

call this method like this if you have a `dict`, and want to get keys between (and including) 2 and 4 (note: this again assumes that all keys of the dictionary are numbers):

```
var splicedDict = spliceDict(dict, 2, 4);
```

Comment: sorry but the method is not working.This method i think will work only if you know the dictionary keys, and i dont know them

Comment: there is no error..it works wee if the ids are from 0 to 40, but i got no elements if the ids of the queryset are from 40 to 70 for example.